# How do I get the inner html based of the position of the on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I new to react to so an explanation would be great to your solution, I have a table that renders data from my database, I have a function delete question seen in the image below, I need the question id the number to the right of the button. The problem is I cant get the questionid based off the button clicked in the table. Say for example I click the delete button I want the login id sent as an argument to my function deletequestion. Any method is ok, Feel free to change any existing code if necessary.
[image: How the table renders currently]

Component that renders the table.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { currentloginid } from '../login/loginid.js';
import { deletequestion } from '../question/deletequestion.js';

export const ViewQuestionComponent = () => {
  let [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const handleViewQuestion = async () => {
    try {      
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=viewquestion', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      const result = await data;
      setState(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ViewQuestion onClick={handleViewQuestion} />
      <div id="questions">
        <Table rows={state}>
          <DeleteButton onClick={deletequestion} />
        </Table>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
};

export function ViewQuestion({onClick}) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={onClick}>View Question</Button>
    );
}

export default ViewQuestion;

const Table = ({rows, children}) => (
  <table className="ui single line table">
    <tbody>
     { rows.map(row =>
       <tr key={row.questionid}>
        <td>{row.question}</td>
        <td>{row.timestamp}</td>
        <td>{row.catagories}</td>
        <td>{(row.answer === null ? "Not Answered" : row.answer)}</td>
        <td>{children}</td>
        <td>{row.questionid}</td>
       </tr>
      )}
   </tbody>
  </table>
);

const DeleteButton = ({onClick}) => (
  <button className="ui negative basic button" onClick={onClick}>Delete Question </button>
);
```

The deletequestion function

```
export function deletequestion() {
  //I need the question id saved in the varible below
    var questionid = ;
    console.log(questionid);
    fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=deletequestion', 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        }
        )
}
```

Thanks is advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, pass the `questionId` as props to the children like below,

`<td>{React.cloneElement(children, { questionid: row.questionid })}</td>`

Table Changes:-

```
const Table = ({ rows, setIdTobeDeleted, children }) => (
  <table className="ui single line table">
    <tbody>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <tr key={row.questionid}>
          <td>{row.question}</td>
          <td>{row.timestamp}</td>
          <td>{row.catagories}</td>
          <td>{row.answer === null ? "Not Answered" : row.answer}</td>
          <td>
            {React.cloneElement(children, { questionid: row.questionid })}  //<<<---Here is change
          </td>
          <td>{row.questionid}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Once the `questionid` passed as a property to the child (`DeleteButton`), access the id and pass to the onClick method.

```
const DeleteButton = ({ questionid, onClick }) => (
  <button
    className="ui negative basic button"
    onClick={() => onClick(questionid)} //<<<<---- see here
  >
    Delete Question{" "}
  </button>
);
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-feistel-lxp09?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you! it worked so just to clarify I have to set questionid as a prop before I can send it over as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
export function deletequestion(event) {
    var questionid = event.target.closest("td").nextElementSibling.innerHTML ;
    console.log(questionid);
    fetch('http://localhost/gotaquestion/api/api.php?action=deletequestion', 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        }
        )
}
```